# Exporting RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB as DER/PEM using Windows Crypto APIs

Tags: c++, windows, cryptography, cryptoapi

I am trying to use the Windows Crypto API to generat an RSA keypair, and then export the public key in either DER or PEM. I have my code working and can successfully export the *private* key, but I haven't figured out how to do the same with public key. My end goal is to feed the public key to openssl to verify a signature.

I've seen this question: [Microsoft CryptoAPI: how to convert PUBLICKEYBLOB to DER/PEM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258135/microsoft-cryptoapi-how-to-convert-publickeyblob-to-der-pem)

But I haven't found a solution. How can I save the public key to a valid PEM format using only native Windows Crypto API functions? What am I missing? Thanks!

Here is the relevant code snippets and my order of API calls for how I am exporting the *private* key as DER/PEM:

```
HCRYPTPROV hProv = NULL;
CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, 0)
HCRYPTKEY hPrivateKey = NULL;
CryptGenKey(hProv, AT_KEYEXCHANGE, CRYPT_ARCHIVABLE, &hPrivateKey);
CryptExportKey(hPrivateKey, 0, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, 0, &size);
BYTE* pPrivKeyBlob = (BYTE *)malloc(size);
CryptExportKey(hPrivateKey, 0, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, pPrivKeyBlob, &size);
CryptEncodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, pPrivKeyBlob, 0, NULL, NULL, &size);
BYTE* pPrivDer = (BYTE *)malloc(size);
CryptEncodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, pPrivKeyBlob, 0, NULL, pPrivDer, &size);
```

This works, and `pPrivDer` contains the private key in DER format. I can format that to PEM no problem:

```
DWORD pemSize = 0;
CryptBinaryToStringA(pPrivDer, size, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, NULL, &pemSize);
LPSTR pPrivPEM = (LPSTR)malloc(pemSize);
CryptBinaryToStringA(pPrivDer, size, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, pPrivPEM, &pemSize);
printf("%s", pPrivPEM);
```

This works fine and the key is in the correct format (changing the header allows openssl to read/parse it)

However, I can not for the life of me figure out how to save the public key in DER/PEM. This is what I'm trying:

```
//export public key
CryptExportKey(hPrivateKey, 0, PUBLICKEYBLOB, 0, 0, &size);
BYTE* pPubKeyBlob = (BYTE *)malloc(size);
CryptExportKey(hPrivateKey, 0, PUBLICKEYBLOB, 0, pPubKeyBlob, &size);
CryptEncodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB, mypubkey, 0, NULL, NULL, &size);
BYTE* pPubDer = (BYTE *)malloc(size);
CryptEncodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB, mypubkey, 0, NULL, pPubDer, &size);
DWORD pPubPEMSize = 0;
CryptBinaryToStringA(pPubDer, size, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, NULL, &pPubPEMSize);
LPSTR pPubPEM = (LPSTR)malloc(pPubPEMSize);
CryptBinaryToStringA(pPubDer, size, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, pPubPEM, &pPubPEMSize);
printf("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n%s-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n\n", pPubPEM);
```

This causes no errors, but the exported DER and printed PEM for the public key is not recognized by openssl and seems to be in the wrong format.

Comment: The examples I see all use `CryptExportPublicKeyInfo` instead of `CryptExportKey` for this. The Mickeysoft API's tirelessly confuse keys, key pairs and certificates and are only trumped by the MacApples API's when it comes to unreadability (the grey on white of Apples HTML pages make them literally unreadable, so I'm not sure that's fair, but yeah). I think with `CryptExportKey` they actually mean "export key pair, mainly the private key". Or they target certificates if I look at the X.509 related ASN(1) encoding in there. Or both. Whatever. Note that you need `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure.

Comment: @user2055956 did you ever solve this?